# Error when compressing Assets Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yui-compressor

I want to compress my assets but compressing is not working; I need to understand I am doing wrong in my configuration and if the problem is not with my configuration then what the error means.

Here is my configuration :

```
Yii::setAlias('@webroot',realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../public_html'));
 Yii::setAlias('@web', '/');

return [
    // Adjust command/callback for JavaScript files compressing:
    'jsCompressor' => 'java -jar assets/compression/closurecompilerv20160911.jar --js {from} --js_output_file {to}',
    // Adjust command/callback for CSS files compressing:
    'cssCompressor' => 'java -jar assets/compression/yuicompressor2.4.8.jar --type css {from} -o {to}',
    // The list of asset bundles to compress:
    'bundles' => [
         'app\assets\AppAsset',
        'yii\widgets\ActiveFormAsset',
        'yii\grid\GridViewAsset',
        'yii\validators\ValidationAsset',
    ],
    // Asset bundle for compression output:
    'targets' => [
        'app\\assets\\CompressedAsset' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\AssetBundle',
            'basePath' =>  '@webroot',
            'baseUrl' => '@web',
            'js' => 'js/all-{hash}.js',
            'css' => 'css/all-{hash}.css',
        ],
    ],
    // Asset manager configuration:
    'assetManager' => [
        'basePath' => '@webroot/js',
        'baseUrl' => '@web/css',
    ],
];
```

And the error is starting from :

> C:/wamp/www/coutde/public_html/js/all-temp.js.tmp:1930: WARNING -
>   Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being
>   used. $("#diffusion-nom").val(data.reussite.nom).focus; ^
>
> C:/wamp/www/coutde/public_html/js/all-temp.js.tmp:2166: WARNING -
>   Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being
>   used. $("#prix-cout").val(data.reussite.cout).focus; ^
>
> C:/wamp/www/coutde/public_html/js/all-temp.js.tmp:2240: WARNING -
>   Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being
>   used. $("#schedule-details").val(data.reussite.details).focus; ^
>
> C:/wamp/www/coutde/public_html/js/all-temp.js.tmp:2317: WARNING -
>   Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being
>   used. nom.val(data.reussite.nom).focus; ^
>
> 0 error(s), 9 warning(s) JavaScript files compressed into
>   'C:\wamp\www\coutde\public_html/js/all-temp.js'. Compressing CSS
>   files... java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   wampwwwcoutdepublic_html\css\all-temp.css:\wamp\www\coutde\public_html\css\all-temp.css.tmp
>   (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at
>   com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor.main(YUICompressor.java:208)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:21)
>   Error: Unable to compress CSS files into
>   'C:\wamp\www\coutde\public_html/css/all-temp.css'.

Comment: I think you have a problem with \ and / because of using windows. wampwwwcoutdepublic_html would indicate that.

Comment: Then @MihaiP. what should I do?

Comment: I saw the same errors on non yii2 applications. Try finding solutions on google. Have you tried it on a linux virtual machine? You can set one up easy with vagrant and this website https://puphpet.com/#create

Comment: Having the same issue at the moment. Also on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Try yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar - had same error and it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you be more specific and write more detailed answer? How to use it and how this helped you with similar problem?